# Parent Child Query without using SubQuery

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Let say I have two tables,

Table A

```
ID  Name
--  ----
 1   A
 2   B
```

Table B

```
AID  Date
--  ----
 1   1/1/2000
 1   1/2/2000
 2   1/1/2005
 2   1/2/2005
```

Now I need this result without using sub query,

```
ID  Name  Date
--  ----  ----
 1   A    1/2/2000
 2   B    1/2/2005
```

I know how to do this using sub query but I want to avoid using sub query for some reason?

Comment: How should the result dates be chosen? last date for each ID?

Comment: Go back to the person who wrote this spec and tell them to refrain from including implementation details in their designs.

Comment: @onedaywhen, What do you mean?

Comment: @user960567 - Presumably that is more productive to phrase your questions without arbitrarily eliminating possibilities such as sub queries. In some cases they are the best solution.

Comment: @MartinSmith, I know about this. But I have some complex queries. When I compare JOIN with sub query then I found that JOIN is more effective in my case. However, I am still using sub query at lot of places.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I got your meaning right and you need the latest date from TableB, then the query below should do it:

```
select a.id,a.name,max(b.date)
from TableA a
join TableB b on b.aid = a.id
group by a.id,a.name
```

Comment: This looks very fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Name, MAX(B.Date)
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
    ON B.ID = A.ID
GROUP BY A.id, A.name
```

It's a simple aggregation.  Looks like you want the highest date per id/name combo.

Comment: Thanks, dasblinkenlight also has the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table #t1 (id int, Name varchar(10))
create table #t2 (Aid int, Dt date)

insert #t1 values (1, 'A'), (2, 'B')
insert #t2 values (1, '1/1/2000'), (1, '1/2/2000'), (2, '1/1/2005'), (2, '1/2/2005')


;WITH cte (AId, MDt)
as
(
select Aid, MAX(Dt) from #t2 group by AiD
)
select #t1.Id, #t1.Name, cte.MDt
from #t1
join cte
    on cte.AId = #t1.Id
```

Comment: Novel solution.  A `CTE` is very close to a subquery though...it's basically a disposable view.